# Difference between "alpha" and "start_alpha"

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I want to train a Word2Vec model using "gensim". I want to determine the initial rating rate. However, it is written that both "alpha" and "start_alpha" parameters can be used to do so. What is the difference between them? Are they the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `alpha` is used in [the constructor](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec):

> classgensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences=None, corpus_file=None,
> vector_size=100, alpha=0.025, window=5, min_count=5,
> max_vocab_size=None, sample=0.001, seed=1, workers=3,
> min_alpha=0.0001, sg=0, hs=0, negative=5, ns_exponent=0.75,
> cbow_mean=1, hashfxn=, epochs=5, null_word=0,
> trim_rule=None, sorted_vocab=1, batch_words=10000, compute_loss=False,
> callbacks=(), comment=None, max_final_vocab=None)

whereas the parameter `start_alpha` is used in the [train](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.train) method:

> train(corpus_iterable=None, corpus_file=None, total_examples=None,
> total_words=None, epochs=None, start_alpha=None, end_alpha=None,
> word_count=0, queue_factor=2, report_delay=1.0, compute_loss=False,
> callbacks=(), **kwargs)

As for which to use:

> `start_alpha` (float, optional) – Initial learning rate. If supplied,
> replaces the starting `alpha` from the constructor, for this one call
> to`train()`. Use only if making multiple calls to train(), when you
> want to manage the alpha learning-rate yourself (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

They're essentially the same. If you specify non-default values in the constructor:

- they're cached inside the model as `alpha` & `min_alpha`
- if you also took the option of specifying a training corpus in the constructor (`sentences`/`corpus_iterable`/`corpus_file`), the `alpha` & `min_alpha` will become the `start_alpha`, `end_alpha` for the automatic `.train()`

If you instead call `.train()` explicitly:

- you can specify a `start_alpha` & `end_alpha`, just for that call, that will be used instead of the values set during the constructor (but won't be cached in the model for future calls)

**If** you're calling `.train()` multiple times on the same model some reason – which is usually an unnecessary bad idea, except in some non-standard expert-usage situations – it's likely you'd want to properly choose the right progression of `alpha` ranges across each call (so that it's not bouncing up-and-down nonsensically).

That expert use is the real reason the separate, non-cached `start_alpha` & `end_alpha` parameters exist. Most users should stick with the defaults (so not use any of these), and if they ever do get to the point of tinkering, just try different `alpha` values in the constructor, carefully monitoring if it helps or not.